# Juego de Dados python

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer un juego donde participen dos jugadores al mismo tiempo. Consiste en tirar 3 dados y obtener puntos a partir de las distintas combinaciones. el primero en llegar a 5000 gana. 
Una de las opciones del juego es ver un "**ranking historico de partidas ganadas**" y "**el maximo puntaje de todos los tiempos**"
no estoy sabiendo donde y que poner para hacer eso.

```
  from os import system, path, sys
import pickle 
import random

jugadores = []
puntaje_para_ganar = 5000
jugador_player = 0
puntaje1 = 0
puntaje2 = 0
# puntajes_maximos = ["", 0] 

def buscar_jugador(nom):
    pos = 0
    jugador = None
    while pos < len(jugadores) and jugador == None:
        jds = jugadores[pos]
        if jds["nombre"] == nom:
            jugador = jds
        pos += 1
    return jugador

def buscar_jugador2(nom2):
    pos = 0
    jugador2 = None
    while pos < len(jugadores) and jugador2 == None:
        jds = jugadores[pos]
        if jds["nombre"] == nom2:
            jugador2 = jds
        pos += 1
    return jugador2

def nuevo_jugador():    
    global jugador_player
    system("cls")
    nom = input("Ingrese el nombre del jugador 1: ")
    jugador = buscar_jugador(nom)
    if jugador != None:
        print("Jugador:", jugador["nombre"])
    print()
    nom2 = input("Ingrese el nombre del jugador 2: ")
    jugador2 = buscar_jugador2(nom2)
    if jugador2 != None:
        print("Jugador:", jugador2["nombre"])
    print()

    while jugador == None:
        print()
        print("El jugador", nom, "no existe")
        input("Presione ENTER para crear nuevo jugador")
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo jugador_1: ")
        jugador = {"nombre":nombre, "partidas":0, "puntos":0}
        jugadores.append(jugador)
        print("Jugador Creado! Presione ENTER para continuar")
        print()
        print("Hola! ",nombre)
        print()
        input("Presione ENTER para continuar")

    while jugador2 == None:
        print()
        print("El jugador",nom2, "no existe")
        input("Presione ENTER para crear nuevo jugador")
        nombre2 = input("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo jugador_2: ")
        jugador2 = {"nombre":nombre2, "partidas":0, "puntos":0}
        jugadores.append(jugador2)
        print("Jugador Creado! Presione ENTER para continuar")
        print()
        print("Hola! ",nombre2)
        print()
        input("Presione ENTER para continuar")

    return jugador, jugador2

def nueva_partida():
    system("cls")
    print("BIENVENIDOS!")
    print()
    input("Presione ENTER para comenzar")
    jugador = nuevo_jugador()
    print()
    print("EL PUNTAJE PARA GANAR ES: " , str(puntaje_para_ganar))
    print()
    jugar = input("Presione Enter Para Tirar Dados")
    jugador == jugar
    print("Comenzó la partida:")
    turno_jugador_1 = True
    puntos_turno = turno(turno_jugador_1)
    return puntos_turno
# jugador.partidas += partidas
# guardar_jugadores()
# # guardar_puntajes_maximos()

def turno(turno_jugador_1):
    resp = "S"
    total_tiro = 0
    continuar = True
    tirada = 1
    puntaje1 =0
    puntaje2 = 0
    while (continuar):
        if (turno_jugador_1):
            print("Turno jugador 1")
            tirada = obtener_puntaje()
            if(tirada==0):
                total_tiro=0
                puntajes1 =total_tiro
            else:
                total_tiro += tirada
                puntajes1 = total_tiro
            print ("Puntaje de jugador 1:", puntajes1)
            print() 

        else:
            print("Turno jugador 2")
            tirada = obtener_puntaje()
            if(tirada==0):
                total_tiro =0
                puntajes2=total_tiro
            else:
                total_tiro += tirada
                puntajes2 = total_tiro
            print ("Puntaje de jugador 2:", puntajes2) 
            print ()

        if  puntaje1 + total_tiro >= puntaje_para_ganar or puntaje2 + total_tiro >= puntaje_para_ganar:
            continuar = False
            if(turno_jugador_1):
                print("HA GANADO EL JUGADOR 1")
                input("Presione ENTER para salir")
            else:
                print("HA GANADO EL JUGADOR 2")
                input("Presione ENTER para salir")
        elif total_tiro ==0:
            turno_jugador_1 = not(turno_jugador_1)

        else:
            resp = str.upper(input("Desea seguir tirando? (S/N)"))
            if(resp=="N"):
                print ()
                resp2 = str.upper(input("Desea salir del juego? (S/N)"))
                if (resp2=="N"):
                    turno_jugador_1 = not(turno_jugador_1)
                else:
                    print ()
                    print ()
                    print ("LA PARTIDA FINALIZO")
                    continuar=False  
                    input("Presione ENTER para continuar")
    return puntaje1, puntaje2        

def obtener_puntaje():
    dados = tirar_dados()
    if dados[0]==dados[1]==dados[2]:
        return 1000
    elif dados[0]==dados[1] or dados[1]==dados[2] or dados[0]==dados[2]:
        return 500
    elif dados[0]==1 and dados[1]==6 or dados[0]==6 and dados[1]==1 or dados[1]==1 and dados[2]==6 or dados[1]==6 and dados[2]==1 or dados[0]==1 and dados[2]==6 or dados[1]==6 and dados[2]==1:
        return 100
    elif dados[0]==1 or dados[1]==1 or dados[2]==1 or dados[0]==6 or dados[1]==6 or dados[2]==6:
        return 50
    else:
        return 0 

def tirar_dados():
    dados  = [random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6)]
    print("dado 1:",dados[0])
    print("dado 2:",dados[1])
    print("dado 3:",dados[2])
    return dados

#def maximo_puntaje():
    #system("cls")
    #print("El Maximo Puntaje de Todos Los Tiempos es:")
    #for jugador in jugadores:
    #    pts = 
    #    print(jugador["nombre"], "puntos", pts)
    #print()
    #input("Presione ENTER para continuar")
    #return pts

def listar_jugadores(jugadores):
    system("cls")
    print("Nombre  Partidas")
    for jugador in jugadores:
        print(jugador["nombre"], jugador["partidas"])
    print()
    input("Presione ENTER para continuar")

def cambiar_puntaje():
    system ("cls")
    global puntaje_para_ganar
    print()
    puntaje_nuevo = int(input("Escriba puntaje maximo del juego: "))
    puntaje_para_ganar == int(puntaje_nuevo)
    return int(puntaje_nuevo)

def guardar_jugadores():
    ruta_archivo = path.join(sys.path[0], "kamikaze.bin")
    archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "wb+")
    pickle.dump(jugadores,archivo)
    archivo.close()

def cargar_jugadores():
    global jugadores
    ruta_archivo = path.join(sys.path[0], "kamikaze.bin") 
    if path.isfile(ruta_archivo):
        archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "rb+")
        jugadores = pickle.load(archivo)
        archivo.close()
    else: 
        jugadores = []

# def guardar_puntajes_maximos ():
#     ruta_archivo = path.join (sys.path[0], "maximos.bin")
#     archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "wb")
#     pickle.dump (puntajes_maximos,archivo)
#     archivo.close()
# def cargar_puntajes_maximos ():
#     global puntajes_maximos
#     ruta_archivo = path.join (sys.path[0], "maximos.bin")
#     if path.isfile(ruta_archivo):
#         archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "rb")
#         puntajes_maximos = pickle.load (archivo)
#         archivo.close ()
#     else :
#         puntajes_maximos = {} 

def mostrar_menu():
    system("cls")    
    print("1. Nueva Partida")
    print("2. Lista de jugadores")
    print("3. Maximo puntaje de todos los tiempos")
    print("4. Cambiar puntaje para ganar partidas")
    print("5. Guardar y Salir")
    print()

def pedir_opcion():
    opcion = input("Ingrese una opción: ")
    while opcion != "1" and opcion != "2" and opcion != "3" and opcion != "4" and opcion != "5":
        mostrar_menu()
        print("Opción inválida")        
        opcion = input("Ingrese una opción: ")
    return opcion

#dados = tirar_dados()
cargar_jugadores()
# cargar_puntajes_maximos()
mostrar_menu()
opcion = pedir_opcion()
while opcion != "5":
    if opcion == "1":
        nueva_partida()
        print("opcion 1")
    elif opcion == "2":
        listar_jugadores(jugadores) # FALTA ARREGLAR ESO
        print("opcion 2")               
    elif opcion == "3":
        maximo_puntaje() #FALTA HACER ESTO
        print("opcion 3")
    elif opcion == "4":
        puntaje_para_ganar = cambiar_puntaje()
        print("opcion 4")
    elif opcion == "5":
        guardar_jugadores()
        print("opcion 5")
    mostrar_menu()
    opcion = pedir_opcion()

guardar_jugadores()

print("Adiós!")
```

Comment: Hola. Si necesitas persistir el puntaje máximo vas a necesitar algún tipo de base de datos. Se me ocurre que puedes usar SQLite para no entrar en mucha complejidad.

Comment: Veo que ya estás usando `pickle` para guardar en disco información sobre los jugadores. Bastaría hacer un poco más compleja la estructura de datos de los jugadores. En vez de una lista de nombres puedes guardar un diccionario, cuyas claves sean los nombres de los jugadores y los valores las puntuaciones. El mismo codigo que tienes para guardar/cargar jugadores guardaría/cargaría entonces las puntuaciones. Bastaría procesarlo después para separar solo los nombres, o imprimir el ranking. Inténtalo y plantea las dudas que encuentres.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia . El tema es que soy muy nuevo en Python y no entiendo mucho. Tengo que entregar este trabajo terminado en 4hs y no puedo salir de esto. He probado mil cosas pero no me va saliendo.

Comment: El máximo puntaje de todos los tiempos no parece difícil, pero el "ranking histórico" necesita definirse un poco mejor. ¿Hay jugadores fijos o son diferentes cada vez? Si son diferentes ¿hay que guardar el histórico de todos ellos? ¿Cómo de larga esa historia (número de partidas a guardar)? Qué es exactamente lo que hay que guardar en ese "histórico" ¿simplemente cuántas partidas ganó cada jugador, o la fecha en que se ganó cada una, o qué? Por otro lado, aunque podemos ayudarte, no podemos hacerte los deberes

Comment: Los jugadores se van creando a medida que el usuario los ingresa y se guardan. osea que si ya jugaste una partida y volves a poner tu nombre te reconoce. lo que se guarda en ese "historico" es cada partida que ganas (agustin 3 partidas, juan 2, etc).
Lo de el maximo puntaje lo puse asi pero no me esta andando.

def mostrar_record():
    system("cls")
    if maximo[0] != "":
        print((puntajes_maximos[0]) + " - " + str(puntajes_maximos[1]) + " puntos")
    else:
        print("Nadie tiene el récord.")

Answer (score 1):

Sin llegar a implementarte la solución, pues es un ejercicio de clase, te doy algunas ideas.

En lugar de usar una lista de diccionarios para guardar los jugadores, usa un diccionario de enteros. La clave será el nombre del jugador, y el valor será un entero con el número de partidas ganadas. No sé si necesitas también guardar la puntuación que ha obtenido en la última partida, pero puedes extenderlo tú a partir de esta idea.

Por ejemplo este diccionario podría tener, después de varias partidas:

```
data = { 
  'Agustin': 3,
  'Juan': 2,
  'Alfonso': 0
}
```

En cuanto al puntaje máximo, podrias añadir una variable global a tu programa, llamada por ejemplo `record`, que podría ser una pareja con dos elementos, uno de tipo entero para guardar el récord hasta ese momento y otra de tipo string para guardar el nombre del jugador. Por ejemplo:

```
record = [5300, "Agustin"]
```

Aunque naturalmente estas variables (`data` y `record`) no las inicializarías directamente en el código como acabo de mostrar, sino que las cargarías del pickle, o les darías un valor inicial si el fichero no existe porque es la primera vez que se ejecuta. Por ejemplo, la función que lee estos datos del fichero podría ser algo como lo siguiente (basándome en lo tuyo para no cambiarlo mucho):

```
def cargar_datos(nombre_fichero):
    global data
    global record
    ruta_archivo = path.join(sys.path[0], nombre_fichero) 
    if path.isfile(ruta_archivo):
        archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "rb+")
        data, record = pickle.load(archivo)
        archivo.close()
    else: 
        data = {}         #  Esto es un diccionario vacío
        record = [0, ""]  # Record es 0, sin jugador
```

Y desde el programa principal la llamarías así:

```
cargar_datos("kamikaze.bin")
```

Guardarlo en  fichero sería similar:

```
def guardar_datos(nombre_fichero):
    ruta_archivo = path.join(sys.path[0], nombre_fichero)
    archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "wb+")
    pickle.dump((data, record),archivo)
    archivo.close()
```

Para añadir jugadores nuevos al diccionario, usarás su nombre como clave, y le asignarás como valor 0, pues aún no ha ganado ninguna partida. Algo como esto:

```
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo jugador_1: ")
    # Esta variable jugador la dejo como estaba, aunque quizás no
    # necesites ahora guardar las "partidas", sino sólo el nombre y los puntos
    jugador = {"nombre":nombre, "partidas":0, "puntos":0}
    if nombre not in data:
        data[nombre] = 0     # Un jugador nuevo se añade
```

Cuando el jugador gane alguna partida, puedes incrementar su contador así:

```
data[jugador["nombre"]] += 1
```

Para actualizar el record, debes comparar la puntuación obtenida por cada jugador con `record[0]`, asignándole un nuevo valor cuando sea mayor, almacenando también el nombre del jugador que la obtuvo en `record[1]`.

Para mostrar el histórico basta iterar por el diccionario `data` con algo como lo siguiente:

```
for nombre, ganadas in data.items():
    print("Jugador {}: {} partidas ganadas".format(nombre, ganadas))
```

El orden en que aparecerán será en general arbitrario. Si quieres que salgan por orden alfabético puedes usar `sorted()`:

```
for nombre, ganadas in sorted(data.items()):
    print("Jugador {}: {} partidas ganadas".format(nombre, ganadas))
```

y si quisieras que salieran ordenados de mayor a menor número de partidas ganadas podrías usar esta otra forma:

```
for nombre, ganadas in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda par: par[1], reverse=True):
    print("Jugador {}: {} partidas ganadas".format(nombre, ganadas))
```

aunque es probable que no hayais dado el argumento `key` de la función `sorted()`, por lo que en ese caso no podrías hacerlo así.

> **Nota final**. No me gusta nada el uso de variables globales, o el diseño general del programa, pero arreglarlo exigiría reescrituras profundas en tu código, y prefiero no tocarlo mucho.